# RadGridView Row value Updating, i'm entering value in one cell of row and it calculate and total figure should display in next row cell

Tags: c#, silverlight-5.0

how to implement cell value changed in a RadGridview , when ever i enter number in one cell the calculated figure should display in next row, how to implement cell value changed trigger

plz help me

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can write code inside the CellValueChanged event

```
   void radGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, GridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.Name == "Val")
        {
            e.Row.Cells["Colname"].Value = (int)e.Value + 'someting';
        }
    }
```

Comment: for me the CellValueChanged evnet is not appearing in VS2012.for me intellisense  feature showing only cellValidate CellValidating cellLoading CellUnloading showing.. there is no cellvaluechanged event...

Comment: @jeni ,just register it in form load, like radGridView1.CellValueChanged += new GridViewCellEventHandler(radGridView1_CellValueChanged);

Comment: it needs System.windows.forms.dll but my silvetlight application  does not support this dll. i'm Fresher to this ..try to help me out.

Comment: hope this helps http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/gridview/cell-value-change-event.aspx